# How to use nest and rollup functions in D3 to create a bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and struggling understand the nest function. I'm trying to get it working to produce a bar chart that will have three different bars for the years '2013', '2014' and '2015' and the length of each bar to be the number of entries for that year.

I've looked at lots of examples, but I'm missing some of the steps. I'd like to know how to view / troubleshoot what nest does to my data (listing keys and values etc.) And I'd also like to know how to utilise the data in a simple bar chart (what data do I call and what do I return for 'height' etc.)

I have made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hellococomo/zz81pwkm/4/ but can't figure out why I can't get any height on the bars. I'd really appreciate any help.

This is my example code:

```
var fruit = [
  {"name": "Apple", "year": 2013, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Banana", "year": 2013, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Orange", "year": 2013, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Grapefruit", "year": 2013, "win": "0"},
  {"name": "Grape", "year": 2014, "win": "0"},
  {"name": "Pineapple", "year": 2014, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Melon", "year": 2014, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Grape", "year": 2014, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Pineapple", "year": 2014, "win": "1"},
  {"name": "Pineapple", "year": 2015, "win": "1"},
     ];

data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){ return d.year }) // `GROUP BY date`
  .rollup(function(values){
  // `values` is all the rows of a particular date
  var counts = {}, keys = ['name', 'win']
  keys.forEach(function(key){
    counts[key] = d3.sum(values, function(d){ return d[key] })
  })
  return counts
  })
  .entries(fruit)  

var svg = 
  d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data) 
  .enter();

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {return i * 60 })
  .attr('y', 50)
  .attr('width', 50)
  .attr('height', function(d) { return d['win'] })
  .style('fill', 'steelblue');
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, mate? I have almost the same issue now!

Comment: @user2063493 I did get further with it, this might help http://plnkr.co/edit/GPZ6Bt?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you log the value of each of the `Objects` in your `data` (for example, [using the Console in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)), you'll see that the `Object`s do not have a `"win"` property.

```
{"key":"2013","values":{"name":0,"win":3}}
```

As a result, the height of the `<rect>`s is not being set correctly (all of them are being set to `null`).

However, you can also see that you can access the `"win"` property of your data through the `"values"` `Object`:

```
.attr('height', function(d) { return d.values.win }) // <---- access .values first!
```

which will set the `"height"` according to the `"wins"` value in `fruit`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/yojm65nk/7/

```
.rollup(function(values){
  // `values` is all the rows of a particular date
  var counts = {}; var keys = ['name', 'win']
  values.forEach(function(d){

for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
        counts[keys[i]] = d3.sum(values, function(d){ return d[keys[i]] })
}
```

Basically in your nest function, especially in your roll up you need to iterate through the data to expose your data variables. Once you have that you can draw you bar graph accordingly.